# Move data to a new zpool

Tags: zfs, migration, zpool

I want to create a new Zpool and move data from an old zpool

The old zpool is like this:

rpool    [mirror-0   (c1t0d0s0  c1t1d0s0)  ]

I will insert two new hard drives and want to configure a new zpool like the old one.
Then i want to move /data-tmp to a new zfs in the new zpool.

Can anyone tell me the steps?

Comment: We don't provide step-by-step tutorials here.  If you have an actual question regarding performing the above change or run into problems we can certainly help with those types of questions.  Please see the FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that this should be as simple as taking a snapshot of the zfs to be moved, and then using `zfs send` and `zfs recv` to move that snapshot between zpools:

```
zfs send oldpool/my-data@snap1 | zfs recv newpool/my-data
```

(taken from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1448/gbchx.html#gbinw)

Comment: Ok growse, thanks. I want know what else i have to do. I mean: zpool create, zfs create, zfs mount, zfs mountedpoint... etc